# Program to block certain keys

Tags: windows, keyboard

So I'm writing an essay, and we can't use contractions. I wanna make sure I don't so I want the apostrophe key blocked, and for it not to do anything when I press it since it will remind me that I can't use them because I sometimes forget to check it over at the end. Can you recommend some software for me to do this?

Comment: Poor man's method: write your document, then do a few global replacements :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/). It's mainly famous for allowing you to set up hotkeys to *do* things, but there's nothing stopping you from using it to assign a do-nothing operation to a key. You can assign context-sensitive hotkeys, so the special behavior only affects certain programs. For example, you could assign the apostrophe to do nothing when Word is active, but function normally when anything else is active.

As a bonus, once you play around with it for awhile, you'll find you can do all sorts of stuff with AutoHotkey, and it becomes a highly useful tool beyond just disabling keys.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use "disable key software" as search terms to find a particular program to meet your requirements. A number of the ones I located have uncertain descriptions, while one of them popped out as being a bit more comprehensive in describing how it works. The comments appear to indicate that it works well.

[KeyTweak](https://keytweak.informer.com/2.3/)

Having the "free" tag makes it more attractive than the try-before-you-buy versions, of course.